# YouTube: force autoplay of videos that are called via link in browser

Tags: youtube

I have problems controlling the behaviour of YouTube videos when called via browser (here: Firefox).

I use links such as

https://youtu.be/lom2zWhpJXI

which on clicking them (or otherwise handing over to the browser) call the video. The idea is that the video then gets automatically started.

I observe inconsistent behaviour: sometimes the video starts (as desired), sometimes it is only displayed on screen as "ready to go", and I have to click the start button manually.

**What I tried so far:**

I tried forcing playing by using the "?autoplay=1" suffix:

https://youtu.be/lom2zWhpJXI?autoplay=1

which is recommended by YouTube e.g. for embedded links. But this did not change things for me. .

I also checked in the settings of my YouTube account. (I usually watch these videos while logged in to my YouTube account / Google account; although this is not a requirement - the videos would/should play also when called from a "neutral" browser i.e. without any login to Google etc.) But I do not see something like "Autoplay off" or the like.

**Question therefore:**

Any ideas how to solve this?

**Additional info:**

1. 2-3 months ago, it usually was so that on first calling the link, I had to push the "play" button, but subsequent similar links then started playing automatically. However, now, in January 2021, this seems to have changed: the videos never start automatically, I have always to click the start button, for every single video.)
2. The entire thing would not be important if it was only for watching single videos. The idea here is however that I can call several videos one after the other (using a series of links similar to the above), and play the videos in queue - a little bit like a slide show, but with videos; and therefor the videos should start automatically.